# Reading the specification

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Hopefully this will be an easy question to answer.

Under LatLngBounds ( https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds ), the extend() function takes an argument, point:LatLng. Now, under Map ( https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map ), the panTo() function takes an argument, latlng:LatLng. What's the difference between the two? And what does the part before the colon signify? I've seen others too, like other:LatLng.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case "latlng", "point" or "other" is only a brief description of the parameter. The important thing is the token after the colon: It identifies the type of the parameter, in this case the parameter must be a object of the LatLng class.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. I'm having weird problems, though, using the LatLngBounds object (it doesn't seem to accept LatLng objects). I'll search more around, maybe post a new question.

Comment: Let me know, I'm using gmaps heaviliy in on of our projects.

Answer (score 0):

To answer atleast one of your questions: The part before the colon is just a variable description, so you know what you're passing to the function, and (as you may already know), the part after the colon is the object type.

Also, just in case, the difference between LatLng and LatLngBounds: the LatLngBounds contains 2 LatLng's, one for South West, and one for North East.

Comment: Yes, but I was passing no arguments to the constructor, instead using .extend() to extend the bounds as I went. Anyway, it works now, must've been a hic-up (or wrong syntax on my part, which is more probable). I ended up using an array of LatLng's, iterating over it, which works.